# Detect last cell on each section in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i need your help to find best solution to solve my problem.
I have dynamic data(JSON parse) with TableView. My tableView consist of some sections(also parse from JSON). I must detect **the last cell in each section** and after customize it just add round corner. (like new notification view on iOS 10)

So i already tried this code:

```
NSInteger sectionsAmount = [tableView numberOfSections];
NSInteger rowsAmount = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
if ([indexPath section] == sectionsAmount - 1 && [indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1)
```

With this part of code detect and round corner only the last cell in all tableview no the last in each section...Please help anyone.

**Solution:(work for me perfectly)**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

    if (indexPath.row == (numberOfRows-1)) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.bounds byRoundingCorners:( UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
        maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
        cell.tag = 1;
        cell.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    } 
}
```

And forbidden reload cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell = (ScheduleCell*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [cell removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: `sectionsAmount` is useless in your case. Just `[indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1` should be enough.

Comment: As always, **do not** get the information from the (table) view, get it from the model (data source array). Never call table view datasource and delegate methods by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not look against the existing tableView sections etc.

Since **you don't need** to do this for cells and sections that are **not visible** on the screen.

The best way is to check against your `datasource` that holds the information to each section.

This check should instead be done in [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview?language=objc) method. You check if the cell `indexPath.row` is the last cell of the dataSource holding the information to your sections , and do your customizations in there or in [tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview?language=objc).

**EDIT**:

I misunderstood your question.

Here is the check you can do in your method described above:

```
NSInteger numberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

if (indexPath.row == (numberOfRows-1)) {

}
```

Or to check against your datasource which is cleaner in my opinion as I described above:

```
NSInteger numberOfRows = myDataSourceNumberOfRowsForIndexPathSection;

if (indexPath.row == (numberOfRows-1)) {

}
```

Comment: I just find this method before make question. I need detect the last cell in all section which i have, for future customize.

Comment: @Genevios Where do you want to detect it ? Inside what method? cellForRowAtIndexPath or what? You need to update the question and your code so I can give you an answer to what you want exactly.

Comment: I am so sorry, i am understand for why i have big trouble with detect. I also must use didEndDisplayingCell for forbidden reload cell